# Django: Order a queryset by it's ManyToMany primary key in descending order

Tags: django

Let's say I have a Photo Model and a Hashtag model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'posts_owned')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    media_url = models.URLField(max_length=225, blank=True)
    related_hashtag = models.ManyToManyField('Hashtag', related_name = 'tagged_post', null=True, blank=True)

class Hashtag(models.Model):
    hashtag = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique = True)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

How can I query posts in descending order of insertion for the ManyToMany field? The ManyToMany table has primary keys for each row and I would like to sort by the ID of the ManyToMany field.

I tried the following:

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(related_hashtag__hashtag = hashtag).order_by('-related_hashtag__id')
```

But that doesn't work. I need to sort it by the PK in the related_hashtag table.

Is this possible? Should I use raw SQL for this? If I we're to use raw SQL, what would it look like?

For now, I'm doing it like this:

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(related_hashtag__hashtag = hashtag).order_by(-pk)
```

But the problem here is that this is ordering it by the Post ID's in descending order. I also have a Comment model from which hashtags can be created and attached to the Post. So ordering by Post PK won't work. Any Suggestions or solutons?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood this question right.  Well I give it a try.  You can explicitly define the link between your Post and Hashtag classes like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'posts_owned')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    media_url = models.URLField(max_length=225, blank=True)
    related_hashtag = models.ManyToManyField('Hashtag', related_name = 'tagged_post', null=True, blank=True, through='PostHashtagLinker')

class Hashtag(models.Model):
    hashtag = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique = True)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class PostHashtagLinker(models.Model):
    hashtag = models.ForeignKey(Hashtag)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Then you can form a query like this:

```
orderedPosts = PostHashtagLinker.objects.filter(hashtag=my_hashtag).order_by(-pk).values(post)
```

(This ordered list of posts may contain duplicates.)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but the problem here is that is essentially what the related_hashtag table does. The related_hashtag table is your PostHashtagLinker

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same that @steffens21 without defining the intermediate model:

```
Post.related_hashtag.through.objects.filter(id=my_hashtag).order_by('-pk').values('post')
```

The problem is that it doesn't return a QuerySet, but a ValuesQuerySet. And it will contain duplicates too...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) modifier to pull the pk from the ManyToMany table:

```
Post.objects.extra(select={
    'm2m_pk': '''
        SELECT id
        FROM appname_post_related_hashtag
        WHERE appname_post_related_hashtag.hashtag_id={}
            AND appname_post_related_hashtag.post_id=appname_post.id
     '''.format(hashtag)
}).order_by('-m2m_pk')
```

Answer (score 0):

The jazz-band library [django-sortedm2m](https://github.com/jazzband/django-sortedm2m) provides a drop-in replacement for `ManyToManyField` that adds a hidden ordering field (named "sort_value_field_name", by default).

As they put it:

> The provided `SortedManyToManyField` behaves like the original one but remembers the order of added relations.

I'm don't why they don't use the private key, though.